# In the field $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$, find the inverse of $f(x)=x^3+x+3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In the field $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$, find the inverse of $f(x)=x^3+x+3$.

I know how to find the inverses of elements within sets, rings, and fields. I know what to do if the field was just $\mathbb{Z}_7$, but the fact that the field is $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$ confuses me. I don't know where to start.

Comment: First forget about the ${\mathbb Z}_7$, just solve the problem as if you had $\mathbb Q$ instead of ${\mathbb Z}_7$.

Comment: Note that if $f(x)$ has an inverse $q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n
 a_i x^i$ in ${\bf Z}_7[x]$, then $f(x)q(x)$ has the term $a_n x^{n+3}$. So this is not 1. Hence we need the quotient term $x^4+x+1$. 

  That is $$ (x^3+x+3)q(x)=f(x)q(x)=r(x) (x^4+x+1) +1 $$
 

  In ${\bf Z}_7[x]/(x^4+x+1) $, $q(x)$ has at most degree 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation here is the same in ${\mathbb Q}$ as in
${\mathbb Z}_7$.

You look for a solution of the form

$$
z=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 \tag{1}
$$

You then have

$$
z(x^3+x+1)=dx^6+cx^5+(b+d)x^4+(a+c+3d)x^3+(b+3c)x^2+(a+3b)x+3a=Q(x) \tag{2}
$$

Next, divide the result by $x^4+x+1$ :

$$
Q(x)=(x^4+x+1)(dx^2+cx+b+d)+R(x) \tag{3}
$$

where the remainder $R(x)$ equals

$$
R(x)=(a+c+2d)x^3+(b+2c-d)x^2+(a+2b-c-d)x+(3a-b-d) \tag{4}
$$

Then, solve the system

$$
a+c+2d=b+2c-d=a+2b-c-d=0, \ \ 3a-b-d=1 \tag{5}
$$

This will lead you to the solution

$$
a=\frac{11}{47}, b=\frac{-8}{47}, c=\frac{1}{47}, d=\frac{-6}{47},
z=\frac{11-8x+x^2-6x^3}{47} \tag{6}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you would first check that $\gcd(x^{4}+x+1,x^{3}+x+3)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]$ (else $x^{3}+x+3$ is a zero divisor in the field, thus cannot have an inverse).

Then use the characterization of the gcd as a linear combination to write $$p(x)(x^{4}+x+1)+q(x)(x^{3}+x+3)=1.$$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]$. When we project down to the specified field, we kill the $x^{4}+x+1$ term (by the definition of the field), so the desired inverse is the projection of $q(x)$.